# Create User with Tableau API

Tags: tableau-api

i am developing a Webapplication with user authentication. Some Tableau Views should be integrated in our Application. And each user can only see small part of the data. Our idea is, we create tableau users with tableau APIs in background and filter the datasource with some additional configurations...

Now i have a problem, i could not find the description of "creating user" in tableau api reference. Does anyone know, if it is possible?

Thanks & best regards,

Shan

Answer (score 1):

I got it. First i have to "Add User to Site", and then modify the information with "update user".

API Reference:
https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/help.htm#REST/rest_api_ref.htm#Add_User_to_Site%3FTocPath%3DAPI%2520Reference%7C_____14

Comment: updating a user's `fullName` didn't work for me (all the other fields did). I am unable to do so for that field in particular. I just ignored it and sent the `password` and `email`. Note I had to remove the `fullName` field because it caused a  `Access to the requested site is not available !` error with a 200 ok. Note also, its case senstive field names.